# Can you imagine a completely different logical/mathematical system than that we have?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics, philosophy-of-logic

Can you imagine a different logic and mathematics? For example, with a different arithmetic, or even a universe with no logic or mathematics and contradictions? A non consistent system?...

Comment: Yes; see e.g. [Intuitionism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionism/) and [Constructive Mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-constructive/), as well as [Inconsistent Mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-inconsistent/).

Comment: In addition to Mauro's answer, by "a different arithmetic" do you mean something like [wheel theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory)?

Comment: Not only were they imagined but even worked out in detail for centuries. See [What are the differences between philosophies presupposing one Logic versus many logics?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/37279/9148) and [set-theoretic pluralism](https://sites.google.com/site/pluralset/context-aims-of-the-network).

Comment: Yes. In some sense, mathematics is just a set of strings. Imagine a computer writing out every possible string, and a second computer determining which strings are "correct". Depending on how you define "correct", you can have any mathematics you want.

Comment: A lot hinges on what "completely different" means. As the above comments, yes. But arguably there are features of mind that narrow the scope of what can be imagined and eliminate incomprehensible possibilities (incomprehensible because our minds cannot follow them at all).

Comment: Imagination permits any combination of ideas to exist simultaneously. Imagined ideas permit characters in films to violate the laws of physics. But is this what you meant?

Answer (score 2):

> In order to consider the infinite number of logics and to make evident how different logics
>   yield different ontological commitments, we make use of the notions of *antilogic* and
>   *counterlogic* defined for a suitable logic. Here we will not consider any logic in particular,
>   but rather logics in an abstract sense.
>
> A *logic L* is a structure (*F*, ⊢) such that *F* is a set and ⊢ is a binary relation on ℘(F) × F without any restrictions. We use Γ ⊢ ϕ to indicate that (Γ, ϕ) ∈ ⊢, and we say that ϕ is a *consequence* of Γ in *L*. [...]
>
> The antilogic *L'* of a given logic *L* = (*F*, ⊢) is a pair (*F*, ⊢*'*) such that
>
> Γ ⊢*'* ϕ if and only if it is not the case that Γ ⊢ ϕ

http://costaleite.info/logics-and-their-galaxies.pdf

Comment: hey, while this looks like a good and neat answer, whoever asked the question, like me, will probably struggle to understand it due to the how it's notated. why not write it out in natural language??